# Tiling Challenge

Tags: platformer, game-maker, level-design

I have a problem and I hope I am in good hands. I recently started using Gamemaker Studio and I intend to create a 2d game where a room can be tiled seamlessly from the wall to the floor with wall objects the player can interact with. Anyone with ideas or pointers?

PS: I am an artist and have little/no knowledge of gml.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In `Room Create` event, you can just put the following code:

```
// Create a grid of square tiles to fill the whole room
var len = 20;    // Width/height of a tile
for (var i = 0; i < room_width; i += len)
{
    for (var j = 0; j < room_height; j += len)
    {
        instance_create(i,j,obj_InteractiveTile);
    }
}
```

This code starts from position *(0,0)* in the room, creates a tile, then starts moving downwards; when a tile column is as high as the room height (in pixels), it moves next to it and starts again, until the whole room is filled.

Although Game Maker: Studio is a simple environment to work with, it doesn't mean you don't need to learn some programming first. Please, have a C language course first, because there are many basic concepts behind creating a game which can simplify your life only if you do know them.

Comment: Thanks a lot man!. I couldn't figure out what programming language would be best to learn to better understand gml scripting.

Comment: GML is an object-oriented language similar to C and C++ syntax. A basic C course is enough to get started, also I recommend you to read the whole GM:S documentation (press F1 when the IDE is open), everything is explained along with some code scripts and examples

Comment: Also, if this is the answer you needed, you can mark it as "right answer" :)

Comment: It is a start, but Im not there yet. I wish I could upload a photo to better explain what I'm looking to accomplish. I came across a short game called Grandpa Katz made by meowza studios. I want to be able to create a room where u can see a wall in front, 2 walls by the side and a wooden floor that doesn't appear like a Mario platformer. More like EA's Shank, if u are familiar with the game.

Comment: @HanifAdams game maker is little like C or C++. It's more of an event driven language than object oriented.